# Styling of controls inside Toolbar in MudTable

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I'm trying to layout a toolbar inside a `MudTable` with multiple filter controls.

```
<MudTable Items="@Elements" Hover>
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudSelect Dense="true" T="string" Label="Coffee" Variant="Variant.Text">
            <MudSelectItem Value="@("Tyrannosaur")" />
            <MudSelectItem Value="@("Triceratops")" />
            <MudSelectItem Value="@("Mike Rex")" />
        </MudSelect>
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString1" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    ...
</MudTable>
```

[image: Toolbar inside MudTable]

1. How can I control the width of the `MudSelect`? I would like to be a lot smaller fitting to the size of the width of the options.
2. Why are the two lines inside the `MudSelect` and `MudTextField` not aligned?

See this code demo:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOcGYbcXyjfvdMjQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **How to Control the Width of MudSelect:** You've got a couple options here. You can add a container element around the `MudSelect` and control the width of that element via CSS (e.g. `max-width: 150px`) or you can use one of Mud's sizing classes on the MudSelect itself, such as the flex class `Class="flex-grow-0"`, which will prevent the select from growing.
2. **Why the Bottom Borders Aren't Aligned** - You're setting margin top to zero on the text input via `Class="mt-0"`. If you remove that, the bottom borders will be aligned.